# Unable to parse value containing special character? Using sax parser

Tags: java, parsing, sax

I am new to parsing field. I'm trying to write a parser code but unable to get the value with respect to a particular tag that value contains `ampersand(&)`. Please help me to get the solution.

#### My `xml` file looks like

```
<system>
<u_id>10145</u_id>
<serial_no>1800015</serial_no>
<branch_name>B & P Infotech Ltd.</branch_name>
</system>
```

and I have tried with this java code, but it's not giving me proper output.

#### main class

```
package com.satya.xmltest;

import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;

public class SaxTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SAXParserFactory parserFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SaxtestHandler handler=new SaxtestHandler();
        try {
            SAXParser parser = parserFactory.newSAXParser();
            parser.parse("C:\\Users\\abc\\Desktop\\test.xml", handler);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        SystemTo systemTo=handler.systemTo;
        System.out.println("Uid :"+systemTo.getUid());
        System.out.println("serial number :"+systemTo.getSerialNumber());
        System.out.println("name :"+systemTo.getName());
    }
}
```

#### Handler class

In this class the parsing is done and setting the data values to data container class.

```
package com.satya.xmltest;

import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

public class SaxtestHandler extends DefaultHandler {
    String content = "";
    SystemTo systemTo=new SystemTo();

    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
        Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

        switch (qName) {
            case "system":
                System.out.println("inside company");
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
        throws SAXException {
        switch (qName) {
            case "u_id":
                systemTo.setUid(content);
                break;
            case "serial_no":
                systemTo.setSerialNumber(content);
                break;
            case "branch_name":
                systemTo.setName(content);
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
        throws SAXException {
        content = String.copyValueOf(ch, start, length).trim();
    }
}
```

#### Data container class

```
package com.satya.xmltest;

public class SystemTo {

    private String uid;
    private String serialNumber;
    private String name;
    public String getUid() {
        return uid;
    }
    public void setUid(String uid) {
        this.uid = uid;
    }
    public String getSerialNumber() {
        return serialNumber;
    }
    public void setSerialNumber(String serialNumber) {
        this.serialNumber = serialNumber;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

#### My output is:

```
Uid: 10145
serial number: 1800015
name: null
```

#### But I need:

```
Uid: 10145
serial number: 1800015
name: B & P Infotech Ltd.
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Plain: its not valid XML! Either escape the ampersand using escape syntax: `&amp;` or use a CDATA section

Comment: @GyroGearless but i am getting this type of value in my response .

Answer (score 7):

There are some characters in XML that must not appear in their literal form in an XML document, except when used as markup delimiters or within a comment, a processing instruction, or a CDATA section.
[List of characters](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#sec-predefined-ent) and their corresponding entity or the numeric reference to replace :

```
Original Character    XML entity replacement      XML numeric replacement

      "                     &quot;                       &#34;   
      <                     &lt;                         &#60;   
      >                     &gt;                         &#62;
      &                     &amp;                        &#38;
      '                     &apos;                       &#39;
```

you must replace above character in XML before you parse it.

You may use [CDATA Section](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#syntax) for text that is not markup constitutes the character data of the document

Answer (score 3):

You can escape these chars like html does:

```
<branch_name>B &amp; P Infotech Ltd.</branch_name>
```

Or you have use of CDATA:

```
<branch_name><![CDATA[B & P Infotech Ltd.]]></branch_name>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must replace your special characters with the characters that are accepted for an XML file. In your case & should be replaced by &amp;

```
@Override
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
        throws SAXException {
    content = String.copyValueOf(ch, start, length).trim();
    content = content.replace("&", "&amp;")
}
```

Comment: It's not working.It's not providing me the desired output. can you please check it again.

Comment: Are you getting some other output? Or is the same?

Comment: its giving me name= null

Comment: i think you should debug your code and check whether do you get you name as null in endElement method or content as null in characters method

Comment: this doesnt work, as the special characters are not passed to the characters method in the first place (string is cut at the special char)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the "&" is an escape character it self.

To fix this you need to replace the ampersand with a unicode equivalent, i.e: "`&#038;`"